# Kendo UI scheduler: make appointments that occur in the past 'read-only'

Tags: telerik, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

Is there a way to make appointments slots and grid cells that occur in the past read-only in the Kendo scheduler? It would be fantastic if the grid was editable, but only for slots that occur in the future.

I would like appointments that occurred in the past to not be movable, resizable or destroyable.

Ideally, I would still be able to double click on them to load my custom form as read-only so people can still view the details of the reservation. I would then use template logic to make those fields read-only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a mock-up of how I would do it... you'll probably have to do that with all the previously mentioned events though.

```
---> outside your scheduler but still accessible to it
var today = new Date(milliseconds);

---> events in your scheduler  - in this case the edit option...

edit: function (e) {
if (kendo.toString(e.event.end, "fff") < today ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    }
else {
    console.log("Hope that helps?")
}
}
```

Hope it helps!